# Using Google Drive REST API in a (service) worker

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, service-worker

In a non-worker script, I can use the Drive API by loading the [client library](https://apis.google.com/js/client.js).
But in a worker there is no DOM, and the library assumes that I have it.

Is there a way to use Drive API in a (service) worker? (I need to save files to Drive's appstorage with the `sync` event)

Comment: Are you talking about service-workers or web-workers. What i know is web-workers doesn't have access to DOM and there is nothing to do with DOM if using service-workers.

Comment: Then don't use the library. It doesn't do much that the raw http/rest is just as easy. The Dom access is (probably) to support the auth dialogue. So my suggestion would be use the Google auth-only library in your main app to obtain and refresh your access token, then pass that to the service worker which uses plain http rest calls

Comment: Where is the auth library what can request Drive's appstorage and how to do plain http rest calls? (links are welcome)